# Connecting lithium ion batteries in parallel

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, lithium-ion, lithium

I have 6 lithium ion batteries that are from some Android tablets that I've recycled, they are rated as 5000 mAh, 3.8 V
and have their own protection PCBs soldered to them. The tablets they came from are from hotel rooms so they hardly get used and spent their days plugged into a charger, they are all less than a year old and are identical.

I bought a IP5328P power bank board and plan on connecting them all in parallel to the board. I wanted to see if the batteries are the same capacity so I connected each one by themselves to the powerbank board to charge them up until they were all the same fully charged voltage, then connected all of them in parallel to the powerbank board and plugged my phone in to discharge all the batteries all at once. When it was almost dead, I unplugged my phone and unsoldered all the batteries and noticed that they all had different voltages, one was 3.42V another was 3.60V and another was 3.66V.

My question is, would it be alright to charge them all up in parallel, will they balance themselves to the same voltage again? They each have their own protection board so I'd assume they would stop charging once they are charged?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I recommend you put diodes in series to each battery, protecting them from reverse current that might flow from the rest of the batteries

Comment: When connecting those cells in parallel, you want the cells to be well-matched and eliminate weak cells, even when you use a balancing BMS and a proper Li-ion charger. If you have a bunch of salvaged cells, pick those that are within 10 or 20mV of each other after discharging, and leave out the others.

Comment: So, what would happen if I didn't have perfectly matched cells, wouldn't the protection PCBs, prevent bad things from happening?

Comment: For some values of "bad things", yes. They are in parallel, so they should "self balance", all having the same voltage across them. But what could happen, for instance, is that all the good cells are continuously trying to charge a weak cell and discharge themselves. The weak cell, in some cases, would be continuously charged by the other cells causing it to fail even more.